# How to keep ActionBlock running on any exception

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have an `ActionBlock` that simply processes messages that comes from an infinite loop continuously. Inside `ActionBlock` I make an http post. When on any network related error, the method throws exception and the block is faulted/stopped. This is not the behavior that I want. I want processing runs even though exception occurs. (Keep hitting `Process` method) To simulate my program;

```
private static ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions processBlockOptions
{
    get
    {
        return new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
        };
    }
}

static async Start()
{
    processQueue = new 
        ActionBlock<QueueMessage>(
            async (item) =>
            {
                await Process(item);
            },
            processBlockOptions); 

    while (!Stopped)
    {
       //Read from DB and do logic with item
       QueueMessage item= new QueueMessage();
       await processQueue.SendAsync(item);                              
    }
}    

private async static Task<int> Process(QueueMessage item)
{
    try
    {
        await item.HttpPost(order);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Http endpoint might be broken
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `throw ex` try only logging the error. A throw will stop the workflow.

Comment: What behavior do you want? What do you want to happen when an exception occurs? Do you intent to ignore it? Then don't re-throw the exception like Nico says. The way you have done it now you shouldn't catch the exception anyway as it does not help but hiding the actual stacktrace.

Comment: You are right, I completely forget that `throw ex` lines, when I change that, code begun to flow.

Comment: There is the Stephen Cleary's cute tiny [Try](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Try) library that allows to process all messages, and at the end get either the result or the exception that occurred during the execution of each message. All you have to do is to wrap each message in a `Try<T>` wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're re-throwing your exceptions, and you're doing it wrong:

```
throw ex;
```

If you need to log the errors or stop the pipeline for a while, you don't need to throw anything, simply log `ex.ToString()` and react accordingly. Second thing is that you should use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`, as you're rewriting the stack trace for exception, which doesn't really matter in this case but can be misleading in case of more complicated workflow.